# Looping: Popular value in a specific category

Tags: loops

I'm trying to create a loop to determine the most popular singers in a specific genre (using two columns - a subset of my dataframe). I want it to print out the name of the artists that are most popular for each genre but I keep getting stuck.
if the rows are 1 - nrows
the columns are singer and genre
in my dataframe df2

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language your using but groupby functions from pandas(for python) and dplyr(for R) would be more efficient than using loops. But naturally, loops and base R can be used to solve such problems as well. I will show using R but the same logic will also apply if your using python or other languages. Assign your original dataset to a variable df and rename the columns with singer and genre to "Singer" and "Genre"

```
#Getting the different genres
genres = unique(df$Genre)

#Finding top singers for each genere
top_singers = c()
for (genre in genres){
    temp_df = df[df$Genre = genre,]
    singers = data.frame(count = summary(as.factor(temp_df$Singer)))
    singers$temp = 1 #so R does not auto-convert the data frame to vector in the next step
    top_singer = rownames(singer[order(singers$count),][1]
    top_singers = c(top_singers,top_singer)
#Making df2
df2 = data.frame("Genre" = genre, "Top Singer" = top_singers)
```